# Connect to Multiple Database

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

How to Connect Multiple Database in Single App.

How can i Connect multiple databases using SQL adapter in IBM Worklight.. Scenario is Drop down which database selected that database has to connect in app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In current releases of Worklight (5.x - 6.3), you cannot achieve this when using 1 adapter.

In order to connect to different databases your only option is to create several adapters.
Then, for each selected option from the dropdown, a different WL.Client.invokeProcedure code will be used to send a request (different adapter name).

This means you'll probably need to duplicate the adapter code as well... depending on your needs.

Comment: Idan I Have created multiple SQL Adapter.. In Js While Invoing Procedure der i Have if else condition for select box based on the value i have called respective procedures.. is this is raight way to do? in my js file i have hardcoded select box values?? or is der any way to do?

Comment: You will need to alter the WL.Client.invokeProcedure code with adapter name, etc... based on the option selected from the dropdown.

Comment: i have done same way based on Selected dropdown i invoked the procedure. but in js dropdown values are fixed.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Continue implementing your application and then upload the project to dropbox so that it could be downloaded and debugged.